# Programmatically change Font size in .NET Core Console App

Tags: c#, .net, console, .net-core, cross-platform

I've been searching and searching and I can't seem to find a way to programmatically cross-platform (.NET Core) change the Font size of the .NET Core Console App.

Is this possible at all in .NET Core directly, or do I need to build a .NET Standard library myself that supports all the platforms I need to support with native code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to change the font programmatically in the Console app, there is no straightforward way for that, unfortunately, by using kernel API we can do that.

Comment: Have you ran across [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts/) article yet? This solution uses some undocumented methods (SetConsoleFont, GetConsoleFontInfo, GetNumberOfConsoleFonts) provided by the kernel32.dll.

Comment: @kevin Did you manage to solve this? I have a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no .NET Core support for this in the framework. Yes - you would have to build your own library to do this. At first blush, this would be non-trivial... In Windows you have both cmd and powershell shells to deal with. On Linux, there are a variety of desktop environments you might have to support to make this truly cross platform.

In the environments I'm aware of, this would have the effect of changing font for *all* console windows. Is this what you're trying to do?

What is the actual use case for this? Typically, users set their terminal environment up the way they want and leave it. Changing the *color* of the text is a more trivial endeavor.

Comment: My use case is that I'm making an ASCII game based in the Console entirely by characters. So the smaller the font size, the more characters I can have in the console per. line = More pixels to work with.